# UIkit uk-navbar-center not centering

Tags: javascript, html, css, uikit

I am using a very simple UIKIT navbar layout.

The default is for the navigation items to be left align.

[image]

I am trying to center the navbar items by using uk-navbar-center whic yields this result

[image]

As you can see the items are not totaly centered.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="uk-navbar">
  <ul class="uk-navbar-nav uk-navbar-center uk-hidden-small">
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<hr class="uk-grid-divider">
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-text-center">
  <a class="uk-button" href="">Link</a>
  <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-mini" type="button">Button</button>
  <button class="uk-button" type="button" disabled>Button</button>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this is not centered?

Many thanks!

Comment: To center the container, use the .uk-container-center class. For any other block element, you additionally need to apply a width. D youo have the  all UIkit CSS files and minified versions?

Comment: Yes i have the full UIkit css files .uk-container-center is used to center containers. you will see from the images above that "the link + small blue button + disabled button"  are centered properly using the .uk-container-center class. However, I am trying to center the navbar items and the .uk-navbar-center class is not fully centering. any ideas why? –

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. You need to use the flex component. 
If you add the following two classes uk-flex  & uk-flex-center this will center the menu items.

Comment: Thank you!  Just to clarify, add uk-flex to the <nav> element, and uk-flex-center to the <ul> element within the <nav>.